# Lambda not working

Tags: java, lambda

I have the following code. It is giving me several errors

```
 Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
 Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
```

on the code

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    init();
});
```

Is there something wrong with this code or is my Java just not working properly?

Comment: are you using Java 8? Post a [mcve]

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so, what Java Compiler compliance level? Do lambdas work at all for you?

Comment: I am using JDK1.8.0_60

Comment: I am using Eclipse, however the error occurs even when compiling from console. My Java Compiler compliance level is 1.7

Comment: Well heck, first of all, change the compliance level to 1.8.

Comment: Actually I don't even have the 1.8 option. The highest is 1.7 for me :/

Comment: Add your JDK 1.8 into Eclipse's "Installed JREs" tab as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse and also check you Eclipse version Java 8 supported by Luna and later

Comment: @Andrew Thank you! The problem was that I had too old version of Eclipse.