# How to resolve missing folder src/java/test when change jdk compiler version

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I get first error when change jdk compiler for project from 1.5 to 1.7. Therefore I try to fix it by method in the picture but get the below error.

[image: Trying add missing folder src/java/test ERROR]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? How are you changing the djk compiler version? Add compiler build plugin to pom & do a maven update.

Answer (score 1):

Configure JDK as the default runtime. See this - [Setting JDK in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse)

After which, go to Java Build Path > Remove JRE > Add Library > JRE Library > Set the default JRE as JDK version.

That should do the trick.