# Why am I getting an SPADE cannot be resolve to a type error?

Tags: java, enums

I recently decided to start using enum for my card Suit however it seem that I can't resolve this error no matter how I type up the code.

Edited:

```
/**
 * 
 * A basic constructor class that build the card object. 
 * The card object will contain value for both the Suit and 
 * card's Value.
 * 
 * 
 *
 */
public class Card {

    public Enum SUIT{SPADE, CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART};

    // This will identify the card suit.
    public Enum suit; 
    //This will hold the card value.
    //Jack = 11 ... Ace = 14
    public int value;


    public Card(Enum suit, int value){

        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I have look up various answer on the site and look through the official Java Documentation on Orcacle. Can someone help me figure this out?

Update:

```
/**
```

* 
 * A basic constructor class that build the card object. 
 * The card object will contain value for both the Suit and 
 * card's Value.
 * 
 * 
 *
 */
public class Card {

```
public enum Suit{SPADE, CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART};

// This will identify the card suit.
private final Suit suit; 
//This will hold the card value.
//Jack = 11 ... Ace = 14
private final int value;


public Card(Suit suit, int value){

    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

Here a screenshot of the errors:
[A screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzDN6.jpg)

Comment: Please don't change your question on the basis of answers. It makes it hard to understand the answers if they recommend things which are already present in the question. If you need to, add updates to the question underneath.

Comment: The code you currently have will not give you an error like "SPADE cannot be resolved to a type". Please add the code where this error occurs.

Comment: Ah sorry still new to this but learning. Added the error and revert the original code back and added the updated.

Comment: The code you've got in your latest edit is not the same code that is shown in your image. Which code are you asking us to look at? Also, instead of linking to an external image-hosting service, simply [add your image directly to your post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou sorry about that been copying and pasting from pc to phone, it fixed now. I'm focusing on the updated one as that is the correct declaration. However I'm getting the error that shown in the image. Ah I did but it said I been at least 10 rep to do so. So I opt for a more roundabout way.

Comment: For one thing, it should be `Suit`, not `SUIT`. Java identifiers are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enum` is a class name (it is the [base class of all `enum`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)). You need to declare the `Suit` class as:

```
public enum Suit{SPADE, CLUB, /* etc */}
```

Then, in order to accept an instance of `Suit` as a parameter to your constructor, make the parameter type `Suit`, as well as the corresponding field:

```
public Suit suit;
public int value;

public Card(Suit suit, int value) {
  this.suit = suit;
  this.value = value;
}
```

---

A couple of other observations:

- Make your `suit` and `value` fields private, and add accessor methods (`getSuit()`, `getValue()`). Currently, nothing stops somebody outside the class from changing them.
- Also, consider making them `final`, unless there is a good reason to want to be able to change them later inside this class, or you want to expose setters for them (I can't imagine what that reason would be)
- Check the range of `value` is between 2 and 14; alternatively, create an enum for the card values. It's a little bit of one-off typing, but it will lead to much more descriptive code (e.g. you can use `Value.ACE` instead of wondering if you should use 1 or 14 to represent that card)

Comment: I plan to create an enum for value however still trying to figure out why eclipse say there an error on the enum declaration even thorough I made the edited changed.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with the above changes. Does the above only work with a specific JRE? I'm currently using JRE1.8.

Comment: It will work with anything that supports `enum`, so Java 5 and up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define an enum type

```
// lowercase
public enum SUIT{SPADE, CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART};
```

If you want to have a variable SUIT

```
SUIT suit;
```

Comment: I have done the lowercase enum but it would then say that enum cannot be resolve to a type.

Comment: In Java there is no ``Enum'' only enum. You have to change ``public Enum'' suit to ``public SUIT'' suit and your parameter ``Enum suit'' to ``SUIT suit''

Comment: Like this: public Suit suit; public Card( Suit suit, int value) {...}?

Comment: @65-e9-7e-17 [`Enum` does exist in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html): it is the class which all `enum` classes implicitly extend. It's just not a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`enum` is the right keyword you are looking for.

**UPDATE**

To make your code work,change `Suit`(mostly a typo) to `SUIT`(enum declared by you)

```
public class Card {

    public enum SUIT{SPADE, CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART};

    // This will identify the card suit.
    private final SUIT suit; 
    //This will hold the card value.
    //Jack = 11 ... Ace = 14
    private final int value;


    public Card(SUIT suit, int value){

        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why introduce the complication of a value associated with each SUIT value? OP's question doesn't require that: each Card has a value, not each Suit.

Answer (score 0):

Your latest edit shows a screenshot containing this code:

```
public class Card {
    public enum Suit {SPADE, CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART};

    public final SUIT suit;
```

Your enum declaration is fine. The fact that you are getting the error message "enum cannot be resolved to a type" suggests that your compilation settings are targetting an obsolete version of Java. Enums did not exist before Java 1.5.

Make sure you are using the latest Java compiler (1.8) and then go into Eclipse properties for your project. Click on Java Compiler. Under JDK Compliance, make sure it is set to 1.5 or later (preferably 1.8).

Your next error is the fact that SUIT != Suit. Be careful with the case of your letters.

Comment: Ok that work thank!!!! But now I notice that I don't have 1.8 even through I recently install it on my computer and set the build path up. Is there something I must do on eclipse to make it show up?

Comment: Make sure you've set the PATH environment variable for jdk1.8, following [Oracle's instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#BABGDJFH). Then, set (or create) the environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to your JDK directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66). Finally, point Eclipse at the latest jdk (see, for example, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse).)

Comment: I set up the JAVA_HOME variable but haven't found any instruction as what to do with it. The linked question above didn't say much about it. Can you give a bit of advice on what to do with it?

Comment: It's not always necessary to define JAVA_HOME, but it can be useful as there are some software products such as IDEs, build tools, and other applications, that use the JAVA_HOME environment variable to find the jdk directory.