# No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK? - but jdk selected

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, confluence

I am trying to do atlas-run (following a simple tutorial about building confluence themes) I am getting the following error:

> No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running
>   on a JRE rather than a JDK?

However:
I have gone to my eclipse settings (window - > preferences - > java) and checked that the jdk is both ticked as default and is also selected as the execution environment (to be safe, I removed the JRE). I also went to my system settings and made sure that PATH and JAVA_HOME were both pointing to the JDK not the JRE.

Comment: Did you check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13636584/243373) on [Setting JDK in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13635563/243373)?

Comment: Heya, yes - my eclipse settings are correct.

Comment: Do you have a `JDK_HOME` environment variable as well?

Comment: Also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21279068/243373) on SO, and [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25632635/243373) from the same thread. Not sure how you run the atlas-run tbh (have no XP in it).

Comment: Ah no I don't have a JDK_HOME, just JAVA_HOME

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Go to Control Panel --> System --> Advanced System Settings

Click Environment Variables
My JAVA_HOME was set to c:\program files (x86)\java\jre1.8.0_111
I changed it to:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
and it ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Go to project run configuration and select Execution enviourment : CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0 (jdk1.8),
And Click Run now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with maven-compiler-plugin
Adding maven bin folder to PATH variable solved my problem