# Installing JDT on Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna, eclipse-jdt

I have Windows 10 and Java is already installed in my system. But I have eclipse Luna with only CDT installed on it, but doesn't have JDT. Do I have to download java once more for installing it on eclipse or can I just give the path to JRE and write a java program. If yes, How to do it?

Comment: You don't install JDK separately for eclipse. You just have to configure the existing one in eclipse to run your java programs. [Setting JDK in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to install JDT (java development tools) related plug ins but not Java.

You can check what is already installed through Help ->Check for Updates-> What is already installed. If you don't see JDT, please then install JDT.

cheers,

Saurav