# lack of jre on eclipse ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8

I installed eclipse on Ubuntu 16.04 but this code

```
public class WhileCounter
{
     public static void main ( String [] args)
  {
    int counter = 1;

    while (counter <= 10)
    {
        System.out.printf("%d", counter);
        ++counter;
    }

    System.out.println();
   }
 }
```

I'm getting this error

```
The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)
```

and a warning

> Build path specifies execution environment OSGi/Minimum-1.2. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.

So I remove open jdk by this command
`sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*`
and use this to install oracle jdk 
`apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`
but the problem still exist.

Comment: Can you fix your last sentence? I assume you meant "but the problem still exist", but I could be wrong.

Comment: Have you configured the JDK in eclipse ? Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse

Comment: The only installed jre installed is java-8-oracle and has been added but the warning says sth else

Answer (score 0):

I fix warning by doing

1. Right-click on your project
2. Click Properties
3. Java build path: Libraries; Remove the "JRE System Library[J2SE 1.4]"
4. Click Add Library -> JRE System Library
5. Select the new "Execution Environment" or Workspace default JRE

   and error by doing :

Check that the Compiler compliance level is set to at least 1.5 for your project: Project > Properties > Java Compiler and set compiler compliance level to 1.7