# cannot get streams work on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-8, java-stream

I recently installed JDK 8 on my Eclipse (MAC) and I m trying to use the streams.

However, it seems that Java 8 is not correctly configured since I get the following error on the following line of code:

```
List<Eshop> tempShops = eshops.stream().filter( e -> e.getName().equals(name)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Multiple markers at this line
    - e cannot be resolved to a variable
    - e cannot be resolved
    - Syntax error on token "-", -- 
     expected
```

Anybody has an idea what might be wrong?

EDIT 
Also tried like

```
List<Eshop> tempShops = eshops.stream().filter( (e) -> e.getName().equals(name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Looks like you're using `args -> expression`. It should be `(args) -> expression`.

Comment: Hi, could u please be more specific? What do you mean by (args)? can you give an example?

Comment: As in, you need parentheses around your lambda arguments. See [Introduction to Java Lambdas](/documentation/java/91/lambda-expressions/2353/introduction-to-java-lambdas).

Comment: I edited my questions, I also tried adding (e), but still I get the error. Besides anywere in the web they dont use parentheses, e.g. http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627
 and I m using MAC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124896/discussion-between-panipsilos-and-some-person).

Comment: Have you set the right JDK in eclipse? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse

Comment: @SomePerson parenthesis are not needed for single arguments without a type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse Kepler did not contain Java 8 support (unless you installed a patch).

You should use the current Eclipse Neon (4.6.1) for full Java 8 support.

Comment: thnx Greg, I ll move to Neon then.

Comment: This is because Eclipse does not use the JDK compiler, but uses its own embedded compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I created a predicate separately and the java.util.function.Predicate package got auto imported and the error was resolved.

You could try something like this:

Predicate shop = e -> {return e.getName().equals(name);};

List tempShops = eshops.stream().filter(shop).collect(Collectors.toList());