# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, java-8

I'm trying to run a Eclipse (Mars.2) project, but when I run it, it throws an exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException : Unsupported major.minor
>   version 52.0

I researched and I think it's because JDK/JRE version, but I did not find how can I solve this. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: Well, you make sure that the JRE version you're running with matches everything you depend on. Use JRE 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens if you have java version mismatch, change your Java run time in eclipse's project build path.

Refer to this link [Setting JDK in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse)