# I get runtime error in eclipse but not in cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, runtime-error, classcastexception

When I run a program in eclipse I get ClassCastException but when i run it in cmd it does not crash. what is wrong in eclipse? It is the return statement i get the error.

```
    private static <T> T[] tilArray(Tabell<T> tabellen)
    {
        T[] ut = (T[])new Object[tabellen.storrelse()];
        int pos = 0;
        for(T element : tabellen)
        {
            ut[pos++] = element;
        }
        return ut;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the Version you are running in eclipse and on command line is not the same

Comment: sure both versions are the same ?

Comment: please make sure by compiling the source yourself with javac

Answer (score 0):

It's because the JDK version used in Eclipse is different from system JAVA_HOME.

Comment: It is the same jdk. they are both pathed to same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the version used in eclipse and how to do that please see the already existing link:

[Setting JDK in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse)

Comment: it is the same version. both is pathed to same folder.