# Pointing eclipse to a specific jdk

Tags: java, eclipse

I have jdk 1.7 version installed in my machine's java_home setting. For some reason it would take too long to explain, I need to have Eclipse Neon working in my machine and this version of Eclipse requires java 1.8 to launch.

Problem is I don't want to change anything in my java_home and path settings since it might cause other running programs and software in my machine not to work. Is there a way to just point eclipse to jdk 1.8 without editing java_home. I mean use java 1.8 just for this particular eclipse to run.

thanks in advance

Comment: [This will help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13636584/3143670)

Comment: @neeraj: the problem is with launching it. It wont start unless the jdk is fixed