# How to solve this compilation issue related to stream function?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
  List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5");

 stringList.stream().mapToInt(n-> Integer.parseInt(n)).    
 filter(n-> n%2 == 0).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This pops up in the compiler's screen:

n cannot be resolved to a variable
    n cannot be resolved to a variable
    Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
    n cannot be resolved to a variable
    Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
    println cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: it does not recognize  n->  part

Comment: please use the [edit] link to refine your question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, so perhaps you are not compiling with Java 8.

Comment: @Eran Indeed. Thank you for the question edit.

Comment: Sounds like it if `->` is not recognized and `println` after `::` as well.

Comment: In order to have Java 8 should I have the latest Eclipse ? Because I am using Linux Ubuntu for the moment and it is a 2012 version .How can I switch to java  8 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse