# Is there a way to make jre1.8 run as jre1.7?

Tags: java, eclipse

i have a project to run in `jre 1.7`. however, i have `jre 1.8` installed on my machine and is configured on `Eclipse`.

Is there a way to tell `jre 1.8` to restrict itself to `jre 1.7`-- and thus give compile-time errors on lambda expressions, etc, all the additional features of Java 8? is there a way of doing this without explicitly installing Java 7 on my disk?

**EDIT**

Configuring the Java version isn't making it. I also tried specifying the Java version in `pom.xml`.

**EDIT 2**

installed Java 7 already- the best way i guess. thx for the comments.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/jdk_compliance

Comment: @OldProgrammer that didn't work - tried again after your comment.

Comment: No. Why not install both JREs/JDKs? Eclipse can handle multiple JREs.

Comment: Does this answer your question - [How to change JDK version for an Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12588537)? Or maybe this one - [Setting JDK in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13635563)

Comment: well, the JRE will not give compile-time errors since it is only for running and not compiling. It should be the JDK that gives compile-time erros... The compiler has options (`-target` and `-souce`) to control the version for which to compile, Eclipse has the compliance level for this - which sure **does** work, compiling with eclipse ("that didn't work" is not very helpful)! I also advice to install and use the correponding JRE in the Build Path (or risk using non-existent methods/classes).

Comment: Just set target platform to 1.7 either from eclipse (project props) or maven (if you are using maven)

Comment: Just keep in mind that this still wont give you 100% compatilility w with JRE 1.7. There was infamous `Map` related change that breaks compatiliblity and will fail to run on 1.7 if compiled with JDK 1.8 - yep, i had to deal with that in the past.