# Database not found, and IFEXISTS=true, so we cant auto-create it

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am getting error after opening the h2 database console. I enter database name but it is showing database not found error:

> Database "C:/Users/Barlekar/onlineshoppings" not found, and
>   IFEXISTS=true, so we cant auto-create it [90146-199] 90146/90146
>   (Help)
>
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database
>   "C:/Users/Barlekar/onlineshoppings" not found, and IFEXISTS=true, so
>   we cant auto-create it [90146-199]

Comment: Try previous version [1.4.198](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2/1.4.198). I also had the problems after updateing from [1.4.188] to [1.4.199], but [1.4.198] works fine for me.

Answer (score 84):

If you are dealing with the Spring Boot project, please change the JDBC URL `jdbc:h2:~/test` to `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` in the login page, which is the default URL configured by Spring Boot.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Thank you, but how we can change default value of JDBC URL from `jdbc:h2:~/test` to `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`?

Comment: @standalone once you logged in successfully, subsequent session will be populated with last successful JDBC URL I believe, and it's populated from .h2.server.properties

Comment: This will create in memory database and jdbc:h2:~/test is database on filesystem making it persistent.

Answer (score 27):

Use a pre-2019 version of the `H2` database dependency that auto-creates the database every time you run your standalone application. For example version `1.4.193`. Your `pom.xml` should include this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Problematic if you'd like to have features available on later versions.

Comment: I agree with @AlikElzin-kilaka. This cannot be the solution. I don't set the H2 version because I prefer it to be dependent on the version of Spring Boot I am using.

Comment: as long as i use it for learning and testing purpose answer seems to be good

Answer (score 19):

Just append this to the ***application.properties*** file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: After working and failing with the frontend (the console) and other dependency tweaks, this finally worked!

Answer (score 17):

Have you upgraded H2 recently? This could be the cause.

This is related to the following H2 commit:

https://github.com/h2database/h2database/commit/8b53f3999c6c5c3d5ca29020e2657968f4f59ec4

and the change was made because of this exploit:

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/45506

This means that the default for H2 is now to **not** auto-create databases when run in standalone network mode.

If you have read and understood the above, and you still want to allow the database to be auto-created, then just add the `-ifNotExists` flag to your h2 start command like this:

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server -ifNotExists
```

Comment: Please give us the solution.

Comment: @BandhamManikanta As I wrote in the answer, just add `-ifNotExists` to the command you use to start h2.

Comment: @joelittlejohn, I have tried adding `-ifNotExists` to my IntelliJ runtime configuration (under "Program arguments"), but it does not seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AnonymousAngelo you can also add that configuration in your application.properties like so: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;IFEXISTS=false"

Comment: @Anon567, I tried that... the only I got it to work was to downgrade to an earlier version as Shaun Dashjian mentions above.

Comment: @AnonymousAngelo `java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server -ifNotExists` will do the job

Comment: @shvahabi: please turn your comment into an answer, you'll definitely get a "correct answer" checkmark. Please also add that this changed somewhere between 1.4.197 and 1.4.200 because I've just upgraded and couldn't create a database the way I used to.

Comment: @rychu since it was heavily based on current answer I decided not to give a new answer, but just edit it and gave an example to make it clear.

Answer (score 10):

i changed JDBC URL to

> jdbc:h2:mem:testdb

and it's work

Comment: This should be the preferred answer as of 2020.

Comment: @nocdib the most liked answer is just saying the same. So no, this answer should not even exist because it's adding no value

Comment: simple and nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Problem:

> Database not found or test folder not in c:/user/username/test

Copy&paste it in application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Issue was of URL, check it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc0Lk.png)

Maven dependency

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

MacOS Catalina 10.15.4
Worked!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you also have Spring Boot Data JPA in your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

In latest versions of H2 Database, the following screenshot might help you to login into H2 database screen. While in Application run console, we can find the JDBC URL link which is required to start the H2 database console in the browser.

[image: While in Application run console, we can find the JDBC url link which is required to start the H2 database console in browser]

Comment: So, what the answer's author should do to solve her problem...

Answer (score 2):

please change the JDBC URL jdbc:h2:~/test to jdbc:h2:mem:testdb in the login page, which is the default URL configured by Spring Boot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can add a parameter to the "-ifNotExists" start options when booting up h2 db. Programmatically, you can do it this way:

Server.createTcpServer("-tcpPort", "[PORT]", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-ifNotExists").start();

If you are using the command prompt, the same applies

Answer (score 1):

**When we try from the H2DB Console, we don't see the actual error completely.**

**##In Console It shows:##**

```
>Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation 
>(not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149
```

**However, when we execute the command for opening H2 Console**

```
>    java -cp h2-1.4.200.jar org.h2.tools.Server -ifNotExists
```

**##It shown me the actual error which port already used#**

> The Web Console server could not be started. Possible cause: another server is already >running at http://191.167.0.7:8082
> Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Exception >opening port "8082" (port may be in use), cause: "java.net.BindException: Address already >in use: bind" [90061-200]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:622)
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)

**##Solution: Kill the process running on the port. So that port is available to H2##**
**> Find the pid used for the port**

```
>>D:\H2\bin>netstat -ano | findstr :8082
>>  TCP    [::]:8082              [::]:0                 LISTENING       6376
```

**> Kill The PID**

```
>>D:\H2\bin>taskkill /PID 6376 /F
>>SUCCESS: The process with PID 6376 has been terminated.
```

**> Start the H2 Console now**

```
>java -cp h2-1.4.200.jar org.h2.tools.Server -ifNotExists
```

**This worked for me :).
What I feel is the Exception shown on the console have to be more clear to show about port** issue.

**Thanks**

[h2db](/questions/tagged/h2db) [in-memory-database](/questions/tagged/in-memory-database) [java](/questions/tagged/java)

Comment: Please do not use bold in all your sentences.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is not with the url or anything, below is the rule that we have to use in this case,
–

1. For In-memory database:please replace the URL at H2 Console as
   **jdbc:h2:mem:testdb**
2. For on Disk database: use the **jdbc:h2:~/testdb**

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to open h2 console because,

1. There was a spring-boot-starter-jdbc dependency in my project which was not needed,
2. My password and username did not match to those that I specified in the application.properties

here is how you can setup H2 database and console

```
    # you should add these to your application properties

    spring.datasource.username=abcd
    spring.datasource.password=forgot
    # note:leave password empty if you don't need one

    
    # H2 database
    spring.sql.init.platform=h2
    spring.sql.init.mode=always
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

    # H2 Console
  
    spring.h2.console.enabled=true
    spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Start running your spring boot application

- Add /h2-console to the path and specify the jdbc url as jdbc:h2:mem:testdb (same as in the spring.datasource.url),
- The username (abcd) and password (forgot) and before clicking on connect click on save

And here are the dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And if you are using spring security then you have to configure it to allow h2-console

```
    public class SecurityConfig{

    @Bean
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                ...
    }
    }
```

I hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

By degrading the version, the H2 DB is working but table i am unable to see. Code snippet

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class CurrencyExchangeController {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @GetMapping("/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}")
    public CurrencyExchange retriveCurrencyExchange(@PathVariable String from,@PathVariable String to)
    {
        CurrencyExchange currencyExchange = new CurrencyExchange(1000L, from, to, BigDecimal.valueOf(65));
        currencyExchange.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("local.server.port")));
        return currencyExchange;

    }
```

**POJO**

```
@Entity
public class CurrencyExchange {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name ="currency_from")
    private String from;
    @Column(name ="currency_to")
    private String to;
    @Column(name ="conversion_multiple")
    private BigDecimal conversion;
    private int port;
```

**Spring boot main**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
public class CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        SpringApplication.run(CurrencyExchangeServiceApplication.class, args);

    }
```

**app.prop**

```
spring.application.name=currency-exchange-service
server.port=8000

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

data.sql file
insert into currency_exchange(id,currency_from,currency_to,conversion_multiple,port)
values(1001,'USD','INR',65,0);
insert into currency_exchange(id,currency_from,currency_to,conversion_multiple,port)
values(1002,'EUR','INR',75,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

first url to jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
second changed the version of Spring Boot to 2.1.3 and it works

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue and resolved in the following way

- To use H2 Database -  Your application should be running in JDK Environment, not JRE Environment ,  to change please use below steps :

  1. Right-click your project > properties
  2. Select “Java Build Path” on left, then “JRE System Library”, click Edit…
  3. Select "Workspace Default JRE"
  4. Click "Installed JREs"
  5. If you see JRE you want in the list select it (selecting a JDK is OK too)
  6. If not, click Search…, navigate to Computer > Windows C: > Program Files > Java, then click OK
  7. Now you should see all installed JREs, select the one you want
  8. Click OK/Finish a million times. I have used [Georgie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287459/georgie) provided steps here ->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29640138

- In H2 Login console, default URL come up by Spring Boot will be  `jdbc:h2:~/test`, it should actually match with the spring boot application properties
  `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` so replace the url in the login console and click on connect  I have used [Ivan Xue][2] provided steps here ->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56539107
- Please clear target using mvn clean command and allow project to build if doesn't enforce using maven force update snapshot or mvn install and then start your spring boot app again to see the difference

Answer (score 0):

use the below properties in the `pom.xml` and run the application again.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.in28minutes.database</groupId>
<artifactId>database-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>database-demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently, there were two issues.

1. By default, it was not populated with in-memory database rather jdbc:h2:~/test.
2. The db name I configured in the datasource was not `test`.

when I changed the JDBC url to `jdbc:h2:mem:{db-name-in-config}`, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Check The jdbc Url used in h2 console to see if it match what you have specified

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a questions with many other answers, try to expose the Pros of yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
Along with h2 dependency in POM :
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I added jpa, crud repository dependency in POM Like given below and It worked fine for me:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This is not an answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Prateik Upadhyay's answer, if you want to rename your db connection name to something else the only thing that worked for me is below. I am using spring boot 2.2.4 version. with h2 1.4.200 version.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/MyComponentDB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the question is how to enable database creation when database not exists in given path
the default start of h2 database will enable ifexists=true condition.

to avoid this scenario one has to start h2 database from terminal with following option.
java -cp h2-1.4.199.jar org.h2.tools.Server -ifNotExists

once u give this option. can one can create database with in the url
Many times I want to create database file in a specific folder. once u start the server with flag -ifNotExists, you can use below syntax to create database folder of your choice
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/D:/Working/Sri/Technology/h2/data/books
here books is the name of the database. if doesn't exists,
it will create books data base in given folder.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when for the very first time I tried to open the H2 console.
The best way is to, change the JDBC URL and replace it with the value that is present in the terminal, the line which says ->( H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'JDBC URL')
It is the correct way to do

Answer (score 0):

Please use the same URL path that is given for datasource in application.properties file
[datasource URL should be same as given in application.properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25koh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in application.properties solved my problem
(as of December 2023)

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was springboot was using randomly generated datasource url.

```
12:37:20,151 [INFO] - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
12:37:20,689 [INFO] - HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:85c04e46-3f5f-4be9-988a-15c6a65c7c41 user=SA
12:37:20,693 [INFO] - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
12:37:20,719 [INFO] - H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:85c04e46-3f5f-4be9-988a-15c6a65c7c41'
```

jdbc:h2:mem:85c04e46-3f5f-4be9-988a-15c6a65c7c41.

So I deliberately changed the datasource url in application.yml file and used same on h2-console UI. and it started working

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

[image]