# Where to add the -ifNotExists flag to h2 start command?

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot, h2

I'm following this question. [I am getting error after opening the h2 database console, i enter database name but it is showing database not found errir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349373/i-am-getting-error-after-opening-the-h2-database-console-i-enter-database-name/56231336#56231336)

I have the same issue. The user @joelittlejohn provided the answer and the answer is to add the flag -ifNotExists. But I don't know where to add the flag. I can't add comment because it need 50 points I'm a new I don't have 50 points. So I have to ask here.

I'm following a tutorial on using H2 with spring boot. where should I add the -ifNotExists flag to h2 start command? Is it added to the application.properties file or somewhere else?

I also tried the independent version . How to add the flag? I added to h2.bat but this is not working. Where should I add it?

```
@java -cp -ifNotExists "h2-1.4.199.jar;%H2DRIVERS%;%CLASSPATH%" org.h2.tools.Console%*
@if errorlevel 1 pause
```

Answer (score 3):

`-ifNotExists` is a command-line argument for the [Server](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html#main_String...) tool. The option is not supported by [Console](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Console.html#main_String...). You should change the bat file like this:

```
@java -cp "h2-1.4.199.jar;%H2DRIVERS%;%CLASSPATH%" org.h2.tools.Server -ifNotExists
```

To start H2 in server mode with Spring Boot see this post [How to enable H2 Database Server Mode in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55847035/8482479). You may pass the option like this:

```
public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-ifNotExists", "-tcpAllowOthers", ...);
}
```

You could still run H2 in embedded mode and in this case the database should be created by default.

Comment: Thanks, Is this should be add it the h2.bat? And how to add the flag when I use h2 in a Spring Boot project? Is it added to the application.properties file or somewhere else?