# H2 memory database not starting

Tags: database, spring-boot, heroku

I have a spring boot application deployed on heroku, which uses a postgres db hosted on heroku.

I have configured config vars on heroku and am using them in my spring boot application like this :
[image]

and in my code I use a connectionService:

```
 public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            final String dbUrl = System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL");
            final String dbUserName = System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME");
            final String dbPassword = System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD");
            return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,dbUserName,dbPassword);
        } catch(final SQLException e) {
            LoggerService.writeErrorMsg("There was an error with the connection : [errorMsg: \n" + e + " ]");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I use DAOs with CRUD methods to access the database, for example :

```
    public static AdminAccount getAdminAccountById(final int id) throws SQLException {
    final Connection connection = ConnectionService.getConnection();
    final String sql = "select * from admin_account where id = ?";
    final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
    final ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

      if (resultSet.next()) {
        final AdminAccount adminAccount = new AdminAccount();
        adminAccount.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
        adminAccount.setFacility(resultSet.getString("facility"));
        adminAccount.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
        adminAccount.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
        adminAccount.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
        connection.close();
        return adminAccount;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
  }
```

This is working fine on the deployed app, however it no longer works in localhost since I removed the hardcoded db credentials. Also, after reading about best practices, I have figured out that it's best to have a separate DB only for testing/development, so you don't actually run queries against the production DB.

I have tried setting up a h2 memory database but with no luck. It doesn't seem to even start when I check the logs.

This is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rbooking</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Switch back from Spring Boot 2.x standard HikariCP to Tomcat JDBC,
        configured later in Heroku (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49970142/4964553) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>app/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.8</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And this is my application.properties:

```
#PORT
server.port = 8081

#LOGGING
logging.file.name=src/main/resources/logs/application.log
logging.file.path=src/main/resources/logs
logging.level.root = INFO

#SECURITY
security.basic.enable= false
security.ignored=/**

#DB
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

#DEVTOOLS
```

When I try to access the h2 database at localhost:8081/h2-console, I get this error msg:

[image]

What am I missing here to make it start and recognize my application.properties variables?
I have used the exact same application.properties configuration for another project and the h2 database starts and runs without issues

**EDIT**
I was able to make it work by specifying an older version of the h2 maven dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349373/database-not-found-and-ifexists-true-so-we-cant-auto-create-it

Comment: Thank you, I was able to make it work by using an older version of the dependency like one of the answers said in the question you linked to!