# Appium unknow error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'app' option is required for reinstall

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I launch Appium with administrator rights
 I use Allow session override from Advanced settings of appium

All i want is to launch an app from my device, which is already installed but i get this error:
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'app' option is required for reinstall

## And this is the code i try to run

```
package appiumtests;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class Appiumtest {



    static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
             openCasino();
        }catch(Exception exp) {
            System.out.println(exp.getCause());
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }       

    }

    public static void openCasino() throws Exception  {

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();


        cap.setCapability("deviceName","Mi A1");        
        cap.setCapability("udid","1d36c8469805");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "eu.fortunagroup.casino.efortuna.ro.splashscreen.SplashScreenActivity");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "splashscreen.SplashScreenActivity.Casino");
        cap.setCapability("appWaitDuration,30000",true);
        cap.setCapability("", "");
        cap.setCapability("launchActivity ", "old.SplashActivity");
        cap.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "3000");


        URL url = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");    

        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url, cap);     

        System.out.println("Application Started");



    }   

}
```

Comment: Domnu Vasile, the error happens on server-side, so I would advise you to check the server logs to find what the issue is.

Comment: What is `launchActivity` capability? and btw you added a space after it, this won't work. Try to remove that capability and run it one more time.

Comment: @LajosArpad - server logs are here: https://pastebin.com/EGzTcQcN

Comment: @Vault23 i removed that cap and redo. Same error. On the above comment are the server logs. thank you

Comment: `'eu.fortunagroup.casino.efortuna.ro.splashscreen.SplashScreenActivity' is not installed` check your `appPackage` and `appActivity` again please

Comment: Multumesc, Constantin, however, this seems to be the logs of your phone app, rather than the server. The error message "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command." says that something undetermined and bad happened on the server. Luckily, it adds that the original error is 'app' option is required for reinstall, which, if true means that you need to specify an 'app' option.

Comment: @LajosArpad its not. As you can see there are logs of [appium] (that means `server` logs), [adb] and [baseDriver]. Furthermore, there are no `logcat` logs, which means "phone logs". And, like i said before, the original error is the wrong value of `appPackage`

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. I need to figure out which is the correct appPackage and appActivity. <3

Answer (score 0):

For those who wanted to check if you are using the correct appPackage and appActivity, launch this via terminal or cmd.

If this adb command launches your APK file on your real device or emulator then that means [appPackage & appActivity] is valid. Play with Activity names or Packages until you hit the right values.

adb shell am start -W -n ***package_name***/***expected_activity_name*** -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000

Comment: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=eu.fortunagroup.casino.efortuna.ro/com.playtech.unified.splashscreen.SplashScreenActivity }
Status: ok
Activity: eu.fortunagroup.casino.efortuna.ro/com.playtech.unified.splashscreen.SplashScreenActivity
ThisTime: 1423
TotalTime: 1423
WaitTime: 1463
Complete

The app started, yet i cannot launch it using appium

Comment: @ConstantinVasile Try updating your appium desktop to latest, I believe 1.15.1 is already available.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install the app in the device and see if it is working by testing out appPackage and appActivity parameters alone.

You can find out if your appPackage and appActivity is correct by doing following

1. Plug in your Android device and launch the application
2. adb devices
3. If there are device connected. Shell it
   `adb shell`
4. Run this 
   `dumpsys window windows | grep -E ‘mCurrentFocus’`

Refer to image . You will get appPackage and appActivity.

Let me know if this is working for the 2 parameters.

[image]

**Still cannot work ? Test if your appActivity or appPackage is correct**

If the above does not work , do this with the app installed

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

If this still does not work , you have most likely got either the appName or appActivity incorrect. 

Reference : https://medium.com/@ivantay2003/appium-desired-capabilities-basic-cheat-sheet-to-launch-mobile-application-ios-android-75b664367031

Comment: Hi. 
The app is already installed and perfectly working.
I did what u suggested and found:
cmp=eu.fortunagroup.casino.efortuna.ro/com.playtech.unified.splashscreen.SplashScreenActivity
Using these, i still cannot launch the app

Comment: There may be another possibility. Even though I get the appActivity as in the above method, but there could be an earlier activity which was not caught by this method. The appActivity appear earlier but when we shell , it was a later activity that is not correct.

I found out this even when I was using this method. I found out from the dev there was a earlier activity before this (but it disappear very fast). One way is to confirm with the dev this is the first activity when launch.


If app is already installed then set noReset to true. The error should disappear.

Comment: I have amended the answer and added the adb command. If the adb cmd does not work , it is likely appActivity or appPackage is wrong.

Comment: Hi @john - I fixed the issue. All i had to do is to add JDK to Eclipse. I commented above the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue!

All i had to do was to add JDK to Eclipse. It can be found here:
[Setting JDK in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse)

Right click your project > properties
Select “Java Build Path” on left, then “JRE System Library”, click Edit…
Select "Workspace Default JRE"
Click "Installed JREs"
If you see JRE you want in the list select it (selecting a JDK is OK too)
If not, click Search…, navigate to Computer > Windows C: > Program Files > Java, then click OK
Now you should see all installed JREs, select the one you want
Click OK/Finish a million times

Instead of JRE i selected JDK folder and the app launched.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try commands in terminal or cmd

```
adb uninstall io.appium.settings
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
adb uninstall io.appium.unlock
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to manually launch the app first, before running the test with "driver.resetApp()".