# How to solve the error "var cannot be resolved to a type"?

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors, var

I am getting the error for the following line:

```
var playerAmt = player.stream().filter(Card::isTrue).count();
```

Error:

> var cannot be resolved to a type

I am not writing the whole code here because it's quite long and I think it won't help much. 
The same error exists at different places in the code.

I am using Eclipse IDE. I also searched this on the internet but didn't help.

Comment: Which Java version are you compiling your code with?

Comment: @Eran java version "1.8.0_231"  

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)

Comment: var is not supported in Java 8. It was introduced in Java 10.

Comment: @JBNizet Even after installing Java 13, same error is shown

Comment: btw when I wrote on cmd: java -version, it shows java 13. Then, the Eclipse must also be using java 13, right? Or is it not necessary?

Comment: No, eclipse doesn't necessarily use the Java version that your terminal uses. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 10+, change the compiler level on Eclipse: Project Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level: 10(+).