# Change JDK Path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The title is everything I have.
I tried [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse/29640138) from previous users, but they didn't help me. Maybe I am too bad for this but I just can't get it working.

I'm currently trying my hands on modding Minecraft, and so I set up my workspace. Everything is fine but then I wanted to run it.

When running this is one of the Errors :
Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261 contains a valid JDK installation.

Thanks for everyone who will take their time and help me.

Edit:
I will post screenshots of the things I forgot to post.

[Java location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kglqT.png)

[jdk 1.8.0 contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQL62.png)

[jdk 12.0.1 contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twB9H.png)

[jre 1.8.0 contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLkmR.png)

[.gradle Folder contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU9qZ.png)

Edit 2:

After a new answer, I got a new problem.

This one seems quite different because its now saying:
"Execution failed for task ':compileJava'."

[Second Error in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW3US.png)

[Second Error in Eclipse 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gx0S.png)

[Second Error in Eclipse 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0H8y.png)

Comment: Can you update your answer and add a screenshot or listing of the contents of C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261 ?

Comment: Updated to have some screenshots provided

Comment: The errors are coming from [tag:gradle] it is probably that that needs to be configured.

Comment: how to do that then?

Comment: Can you show your `.gradle` file?

Comment: Made a screenshot

Comment: Had to remove some old pictures since the systems is kinda weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can try right click on your project name, then go to Build Path -> Preferences -> Configure Build Path ... Then in the "Libraries" tab, click on JRE, click edit and select the one you want for that specific project.

Comment: This did not fix the Problem

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says, that you are using JRE instead of JDK and that seems to be your problem. You can change or check this in Eclipse Perferences.
In the menu bar click the following menu items: Window => Preferences
In the following Preferences window navigate like this: Java => Installed JREs

There you will see all JREs and JDKs, which eclipse knows.
Make sure that the list contains jdk-12 or jdk-8 by clicking the "Add..." button.
Select in this window the newly added JDK and click "Apply & Close".
Then it should work.

In my German blog, I have a post about how I setup and configure my Eclipse:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/09/eclipse-als-ide-fur-java-spring.html

Comment: This indeed helped in some way but sadly was not the answer.
I also read through the blog since I am German but that didn't help either.

I now get a new error, seems that the Old one is gone.
The main post will be updated soon

Comment: The Post is Updated! 
I just didn't knew how to make a paste bin into a text there, weird problems

Comment: Based on the update, I think it is a gradle issue. You have to tell gradle, that it shall use JDK instead of JRE. I found this about setting JDK in gradle:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version

Comment: Thanks very much, the problem is that I don't know how to do any of those steps mentioned. I am really new to all of this, so I am sorry.