# can not run kotlin project in eclipse java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I'am studding Kotlin, so i created a file with main method with simple println method call in it, and pressed run as Kotlin app and got exception
Error: Could not find or load main class learn.varabls.VariablsKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: learn.varabls.VariablsKt
Error: Could not find or load main class Kt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Kt

Answer (score 0):

it was fixed by changing JDK version of the project from 11 to 8 in eclipse

link if you need help on how to change JDK version

[Setting JDK in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse)