# How to resolve The specified JRE installation does not exist

Tags: java, java-11

I just moved to JDK 11.0.9 from 1.8 and I found out that there isn't JRE in JDK 11 and while executing any Maven command I get The specified JRE installation does not exist error. I have set the new JDK 11 in my Java_Home and in the path but in eclipse I don't see any perfect match for it in Execution Environments panel. I am not sure how to handle this since there is no jre for JDk 11.

[As you can see there is no JavaSe-11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxIbe.png)

Comment: Use JDK11 (as you said, there is no JRE for Java 11)

Comment: which eclipse version you are using?

Comment: But what about the error I am getting while running maven command. In eclipse I have to choose the execution environment.

Comment: I am using STS 3.9.4

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58353576/1189885)