# Error: The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 15 is used

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

So I got an error in eclipse saying "The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 15 is used", and when I try to change the Java compiler, eclipse said `When selecting 1.8 compliance, make sure to have a compatible JRE installed and activated(currently 15). Configure the 'Installed JREs' and Execution Environments, or change the JRE on the Java Build Path`

And when I go to the Java build path the JRE there is 1.8 instead of 15. And after that I went to Execution environments and saw JavaSE - 15 is the only one that has [perfect match] in the compatible JREs box, but if I try to add Java SE - 1.8, there is a new warning, something like `Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE - 1.8, there are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment`

and after that, I have no idea what to do...

Comment: So, did you add an actual Java 8 JDK onto your Installed JREs preference page?

Comment: Do you want to code in Java 8 or in Java 15? If in Java 8, do you have a Java 8 JDK installed on your system or do you want to use Java 15 via the `--release` option for that (this will generate Java 8 code, but all things that have been removed from the system library will be missing).

Comment: so I have JDK 8 installed, and I do not have JDK 15 installed. But in eclipse sets 15 as the default JRE, I don't know how to add JRE 8 to the library, and in the library right now is a JRE that I already deleted. And yes I want to use JRE 8

Comment: so basically I just want to know how to add jdk to installed JREs preference page. thanks!

Comment: Use this answer to set your preferred jre https://stackoverflow.com/a/58353576/11775515

Answer (score 12):

In the preferences do you see something like this - `Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs`

[image]

Either ensure the proper JRE is there or go to the `Windows->Preferences->Java->Compiler` and make sure your compliance setting matches.

Comment: um how do you add JDK to installed JRE? what folder should I put them in? jre(default) is the only one in my installed JREs, I tried to put jre 8's folder to where eclipse stored that default jre, but it didn't work.

Comment: @aliengamer90 SO just messaged me about this answer, so I checked it out.  So I was wondering if my edited answer ever solved your problem?