# SunCertPathBuilderException : unable to find valid certification path to requested target but different issue

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, ssl-certificate, sts

I am trying to import a gradle project and when I try to create a Spring starter project in Spring tool suite (STS 4), I see this error.
[image]

I looked online and have added the certs for both **start.spring.io** and **services.gradle.org** but I still see the error. Could anyone help me figure this out as to what else am I missing?

Comment: It would be helpful if you will add a more detailed error. My guess is that STS points internally to a diffrent JDK/JVM then the one you added the certs for (not sure why you could not use the default in first place).

Comment: What sort of information are you looking for? I downloaded STS from the spring.io website and installed JDK/JRE from Oracle website. Without JDK, it was giving me errors that JDK is needed but after installing JDK, it gives me this cert error.

Comment: What I am saying is that the JDK STS is using is not the one you installed. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse

Comment: That's right. It was using some other JDK. I changed it to what I installed , restarted STS but still the same error.