# How to specify the JRE used during the debug?

Tags: eclipse

On Windows (same question for Linux though), in eclipse.ini, I change
-vm
to
C:\Users\k\bin\jdk-17\bin
Then I can see the change, etc

[image]

But during the debug, I notice Eclipse still use the default jre, not the one I specify, etc

[image]

What's the official way to specify the JRE used during the debug?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13636584

Comment: The eclipse.ini only sets the JVM that Eclipse itself uses. The Run Configuration for your program sets the JVM used for that ("Run > Run Configurations")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change you made in `eclipse.ini` is about the JRE that is used to run Eclipse. It is nothing to do with the JRE that is used to run/debug an application.

To configure the JRE for debugging an application , right click the `.java` that you want to debug --> Debug As --> Debug Configuration. Then go to the `JRE` tab to configure at there. Something like below:

[image]

Comment: Use _Exectution environment_ rather than a specific _Alternate JRE_ for choosing a JDK/JRE of a specific Java version. _Alternate JRE_ makes only sense when having more than one JDK/JRE for that Java version.