# How to run different jre versions in eclipse default

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a project running with java 7. but i want to test the code with java 8 or later.

There's a way to set specific jre version, but i want to set it default.

Everytime i test the code, i have to configure junit jre version.

I want to make it easier.

Is there any possible way to apply default java verions?

java 7 for running, java 8 or later for testing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting JDK in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse)

Comment: Strictly speaking, No. but thanks.