# Java jre 1.7 error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.IntBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/IntBuffer;

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java applet exported by eclipse, but when I try to run, I get this weird output error:

```
Exception in thread "Minecraft main thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.IntBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/IntBuffer;
at net.minecraft.src.RenderEngine.setupTextureExt(RenderEngine.java:262)
at net.minecraft.src.RenderEngine.getTexture(RenderEngine.java:192)
at net.minecraft.src.RenderEngine.bindTexture(RenderEngine.java:126)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.loadScreen(Minecraft.java:491)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:403)
at net.minecraft.src.MinecraftAppletImpl.startGame(MinecraftAppletImpl.java:41)
at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:726)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When I run on eclipse the applet start, but the compiled applet can't be run.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because your version java not 7. You need download java 7 and set the path to it for JAVA_HOME or [setting JDK in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse)