# org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException using java8

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, java-8

**I have added relevant jar files still I'm getting this error**

[Exception occured while running CreateStudentDemo.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzUS3.png)

**CreateStudentDemo.java**

```
    package com.aris.hibernate.demo;


import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.aris.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;

public class CreateStudentDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                                            .configure()
                        .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                        .buildSessionFactory();
        //create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        
        try {
            //use the session object to save Java object
            
            //create a student object
            System.out.println("Creating a new student...");
            Student student = new Student("Paul","Wood","paulwood44@gmail.com");
            //start a transaction
            session.beginTransaction();
            //save the student object
            System.out.println("Saving the student...");
            session.save(student);
            //commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception e) {}
        finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hbstudent</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hbstudent</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
 
    </session-factory>

    </hibernate-configuration>
```

**Directory Structure**
[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFLRU.png)
**Referenced Jar files**
[Referenced jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R09bs.png)

I was trying to perform basic example of saving data into mysql database using hibernate.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, edit your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Java 8 from the screen shot, it looks like you are using Java 17.

Comment: I'm using java 8

Comment: How are you running the application?

Comment: And I'm just learning and working on demo project. So it seems there might be no issue.

Comment: I'm running it as Java Application ( CreateStudentDemo.java )

Comment: You need to configure the correct JDK for your project in eclipse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse. Check the link for how to configure it.

Comment: Yes, it works. I reinstalled JDK , removed unnecessary jar files and updated javax.persistence jar file with latest jar file.